# Configure MSBuild.exe cli builds to run incrementally like in Visual Studio builds

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, msbuild-target

### Context

For learning purposes, I am trying to develop using a text editor and MSBuild from the command line. My goal is to be able to build as quickly as possible using `MSBuild.exe` through cli, by skipping already built dependencies.

As described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-builds-vs-msbuildexe-builds):

> There are some significant differences between when projects build in Visual Studio vs. when you invoke MSBuild directly. [...] In MSBuild, when referenced projects are required, a build actually occurs; that is, it runs tasks and tools, and generates the output. [...] When a Visual Studio build finds a referenced project, MSBuild only returns the expected outputs from the referenced project; it lets Visual Studio control the building of those other projects.

### Problem Statement

Can I configure my `csproj` files so that, just like in Visual Studio...

- Given a `csproj` project called A

  - And there are changes in A since last build
  - And A has a dependency on a project B that **is** up to date (already built, no changes since last build)
  - And A has a dependency on a project C that is **not** up to date (already built, but there are changes since last build)
- When I run `MSBuild` on project A
- Then B is **not** re-compiled

  - And C is re-compiled
  - And A is re-compiled

?

### What I tried

I read about [incremental build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019).

I tried to append the following `Target`s at the bottom of the `<Project>` node in my `csproj` files:

```xml
<Target Name="Build" Inputs="@(CSFile);@(Content)" Outputs="$(TargetFileName)">
    <Csc Sources="@(CSFile)" OutputAssembly="$(TargetFileName)"/>
</Target>
```

- This is the configuration depicted in ["How to: Build incrementally" by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019)

  - I got `MSBuild` errors saying the source files were not found

```xml
<Target Name="Build" Inputs="@(Compile);@(Content)" Outputs="$(TargetFileName)">
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(TargetFileName)"/>
</Target>
```

- The same configuration, using `Compile` item list instead of `CSFile` item list

  - I got better results. But...
  - I got errors saying dependencies were not found

```xml
  <Target Name="Build"
    Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' " DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" Returns="@(TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker)"
    Inputs="@(Compile);@(Content)" Outputs="$(TargetFileName)">
      <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(TargetFileName)"/>
  </Target>
```

- The same configuration, but expanding from [MSBuild's default `Build` definition](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/6819f7ab06c3f43e83ff4059d417395e0af06c01/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L875-L879)

  - I get **plenty** of `CS0103` and `CS0234` errors:

    - `CS0103`: The name 'foobar' does not exist in the current context
    - `CS0234`: The type or namespace name 'foo' does not exist in the namespace 'bar' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```xml
  <Target Name="Build"
    Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' " DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" Returns="@(TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker)"
    Inputs="@(Compile);@(Content)" Outputs="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(TargetFileName)"/>
  </Target>
```

- The same configuration, using `$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)` Output instead of `$(TargetFileName)`

  - I don't have errors anymore
  - But building a second time, with no change whatsoever, still takes time (14 seconds using `minimal` verbosity on a single `csproj` inside a 120-projects solution with its dependencies already built from the first build)
  - 58 occurrences of `Skipping target "Build" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`
  - 79 occurrences of `Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`
  - Here is an extract of the performance report from `diagnostic` verbosity :

```
  ============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) =====================================================
  Id                  : Exclusive Time   Total Time   Path (Targets)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:0)
  0                   : 19.251s           572.393s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | 55                : 0.000s           0.000s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | 21                : 0.245s           0.963s       some_path (GetTargetFrameworks)  (TaskId:0)
  ...
  | 43                : 1.465s           10.801s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | 44                : 3.959s           48.216s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | | 55              : 2.260s           5.435s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | 52                : 6.762s           7.694s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | . 112             : 1.089s           1.089s       some_path (GetNativeManifest)  (TaskId:0)
  | 64                : 5.494s           25.018s       some_path ()  (TaskId:0)
  | | 139             : 0.212s           0.807s       some_path (GetTargetFrameworks)  (TaskId:0)
  | | . 157           : 0.595s           0.595s       some_path (GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework)  (TaskId:0)

Project Evaluation Performance Summary:
       42 ms  some_path   1 calls
      ...
      159 ms  some_path   1 calls
      175 ms  some_path   1 calls
      213 ms  some_path   1 calls
      261 ms  some_path   2 calls

Project Performance Summary:
     2079 ms  some_path  18 calls
                615 ms  GetNativeManifest                          6 calls
                 17 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              6 calls
     2094 ms  some_path  40 calls
                247 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                       10 calls
                437 ms  GetNativeManifest                         10 calls
                  1 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems             10 calls
     2352 ms  some_path   8 calls
                260 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        2 calls
                840 ms  GetNativeManifest                          2 calls
                  0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              2 calls
     2374 ms  some_path  68 calls
                292 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                       17 calls
                855 ms  GetNativeManifest                         17 calls
                 15 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems             17 calls
     2378 ms  some_path  24 calls
                266 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        6 calls
                895 ms  GetNativeManifest                          6 calls
                 14 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              6 calls
     2413 ms  some_path  12 calls
                241 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        3 calls
                932 ms  GetNativeManifest                          3 calls
                 13 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              3 calls
     ...
    34668 ms  some_path   8 calls
                281 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        2 calls
               4564 ms  GetNativeManifest                          2 calls
                  1 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              2 calls
    44339 ms  some_path  20 calls
                252 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        5 calls
               8828 ms  GetNativeManifest                          5 calls
                  0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              5 calls
    46147 ms  some_path   4 calls
                474 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        1 calls
               4288 ms  GetNativeManifest                          1 calls
                  0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              1 calls
    52157 ms  some_path  16 calls
                239 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        4 calls
               3703 ms  GetNativeManifest                          4 calls
                  0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              4 calls
    352737 ms  some_path   4 calls
                419 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        1 calls
              19594 ms  GetNativeManifest                          1 calls
                  0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              1 calls
    572226 ms  some_path   1 calls

Target Performance Summary:
        0 ms  BuildGenerateSources                       1 calls
        0 ms  SelectResourceCompile                      1 calls
        0 ms  AfterResourceCompile                       1 calls
        0 ms  _ResourceCompile                           1 calls
        0 ms  AfterBuildCompileEvent                     1 calls
        0 ms  _BuildCompileAction                        1 calls
        0 ms  BuildCompile                               1 calls
        0 ms  BuildLinkTraverse                          1 calls
        0 ms  ComputeLegacyManifestEmbedding             1 calls
        0 ms  BeforeLink                                 1 calls
        0 ms  BeforeResourceCompile                      1 calls
        0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                 80 calls
        0 ms  ComputeRCGeneratedLinkInputs               1 calls
        0 ms  _AfterCompileWinFXInternal                59 calls
        0 ms  AfterCompileWinFX                         59 calls
        0 ms  ComputeCustomBuildOutput                   1 calls
        0 ms  ComputeLinkInputsFromProject               1 calls
        0 ms  PreLinkEvent                               1 calls
        0 ms  _Xsd                                       1 calls
        0 ms  _Link                                      1 calls
        0 ms  BeforeCompile                             79 calls
        0 ms  ComputeRCOutputs                           1 calls
        0 ms  _ALink                                     1 calls
        0 ms  _ClCompile                                 1 calls
        0 ms  _SGenCheckForOutputs                       1 calls
        0 ms  ComputeMIDLGeneratedCompileInputs          1 calls
        0 ms  _SelectedFiles                             1 calls
        0 ms  PreBuildEvent                              1 calls
        0 ms  BeforeBuildGenerateSources                 1 calls
        0 ms  BuildGenerateSourcesTraverse               1 calls
        0 ms  AfterMidl                                  1 calls
        0 ms  SetCABuildNativeEnvironmentVariables       1 calls
        0 ms  _Midl                                      1 calls
        0 ms  AfterBuildGenerateSources                  1 calls
        0 ms  AfterClCompile                             1 calls
        0 ms  AfterBuildGenerateSourcesEvent             1 calls
        0 ms  _BuildGenerateSourcesAction                1 calls
        0 ms  BuildCompileTraverse                       1 calls
        0 ms  BeforeClCompile                            1 calls
        0 ms  ComputeCLInputPDBName                      1 calls
        0 ms  AfterBuild                                80 calls
        0 ms  ComputeReferenceCLInput                    1 calls
        0 ms  FixupCLCompileOptions                      1 calls
        0 ms  SelectCustomBuild                          1 calls
        0 ms  SelectClCompile                            1 calls
        0 ms  _PrepareForReferenceResolution             1 calls
        0 ms  _Manifest                                  1 calls
        0 ms  AfterLink                                  1 calls
        0 ms  ResolveLockFileAnalyzers                  20 calls
        0 ms  GenerateAssemblyInfo                      20 calls
        0 ms  _Appverifier                               1 calls
        0 ms  _Deploy                                    1 calls
        0 ms  _BuildLinkAction                           1 calls
        0 ms  AfterMarkupCompilePass1                   59 calls
        0 ms  BuildLink                                  1 calls
        0 ms  MakeDirsForBscMake                         1 calls
        0 ms  _gRPC_PrepareCompileOptions                4 calls
        0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                    80 calls
        0 ms  Protobuf_BeforeCompile                     4 calls
        0 ms  AddImplicitDefineConstants                20 calls
        0 ms  GenerateFakes                             20 calls
        0 ms  InitializeSourceControlInformation        20 calls
        0 ms  AddSourceRevisionToInformationalVersion   20 calls
        0 ms  _DefaultMicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary       20 calls
        0 ms  ComputeCLCompileGeneratedSbrFiles          1 calls
        0 ms  _BscMake                                   1 calls
        0 ms  PrepareProjectReferences                  80 calls
        0 ms  ComputeCLCompileGeneratedXDCFiles          1 calls
        0 ms  PrepareResources                          79 calls
        0 ms  ResGen                                    79 calls
        0 ms  BeforeBuild                               79 calls
        0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames         80 calls
        0 ms  _RemoveZipFileSuggestedRedirect            2 calls
        0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                79 calls
        0 ms  ResolvedXDCMake                            1 calls
        0 ms  MakeDirsForXdcMake                         1 calls
        0 ms  Protobuf_Compile                           4 calls
        0 ms  _XdcMake                                   1 calls
        0 ms  Protobuf_AfterCompile                      4 calls
        0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                   80 calls
        0 ms  _Protobuf_Compile_BeforeCsCompile          4 calls
        1 ms  CoreBuild                                 79 calls
        1 ms  Protobuf_PrepareCompileOptions             4 calls
        1 ms  _Protobuf_GatherStaleSimple                4 calls
        1 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFile           79 calls
        1 ms  ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild        20 calls
        1 ms  PrepareResourceNames                      80 calls
        1 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileShouldRun  79 calls
        1 ms  ComputeManifestGeneratedLinkerInputs       1 calls
        1 ms  BeforeResGen                              79 calls
        1 ms  AfterCompile                              79 calls
        1 ms  MakeDirsForMidl                            1 calls
        1 ms  ComputeManifestInputsTargets               1 calls
        1 ms  DoLinkOutputFilesMatch                     1 calls
        1 ms  gRPC_ResolvePluginFullPath                 4 calls
        1 ms  CollectPackageReferences                  20 calls
        1 ms  _CheckWindowsSDKInstalled                  1 calls
        1 ms  AddAssemblyAliasToBclAsync                 1 calls
        1 ms  AfterResGen                               79 calls
        1 ms  _Protobuf_EnforceInvariants                4 calls
        1 ms  PrepareForRun                             80 calls
        2 ms  _Protobuf_CoreCompile                      4 calls
        2 ms  Compile                                   79 calls
        2 ms  FinalizeBuildStatus                        1 calls
        2 ms  BeforeGenerateFakesAssemblies             20 calls
        2 ms  GenerateBindingRedirects                   1 calls
        3 ms  ResolveReferences                         80 calls
        3 ms  GetTargetPath                             79 calls
        3 ms  MainResourcesGeneration                    1 calls
        3 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory         80 calls
        3 ms  ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies     5 calls
        3 ms  CopyAdditionalFiles                       79 calls
        4 ms  WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename              1 calls
        5 ms  CopyFileToFolders                          1 calls
        6 ms  SetTelemetryEnvironmentVariables           1 calls
        7 ms  _PrepareForBuild                           1 calls
        9 ms  MakeDirsForCl                              1 calls
       10 ms  ResourceCompile                            1 calls
       12 ms  GetResolvedWinMD                           1 calls
       12 ms  _ComputePackageReferencePublish           20 calls
       12 ms  ComputeLinkSwitches                        1 calls
       12 ms  _Protobuf_SanityCheck                      4 calls
       13 ms  _CheckForObsoleteDotNetCliToolReferences  20 calls
       13 ms  MakeDirsForResourceCompile                 1 calls
       13 ms  Protobuf_ReconcileOutputs                  4 calls
       14 ms  MakeDirsForLink                            1 calls
       15 ms  PlatformPrepareForBuild                    1 calls
       16 ms  InitializeBuildStatus                      1 calls
       18 ms  Protobuf_ResolvePlatform                   4 calls
       20 ms  EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports             3 calls
       22 ms  _Protobuf_GatherStaleFiles                 4 calls
       23 ms  _ComputeTargetFrameworkItems              10 calls
       27 ms  GetNativeManifest                         79 calls
       28 ms  IncludeTransitiveProjectReferences        20 calls
       28 ms  _Protobuf_AugmentLanguageCompile           4 calls
       30 ms  ComputeCLOutputs                           1 calls
       31 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedNETStandardVersion    20 calls
       31 ms  _Protobuf_SelectFiles                      4 calls
       32 ms  EnableIntermediateOutputPathMismatchWarning  20 calls
       34 ms  ComputeCLGeneratedLinkInputs               1 calls
       42 ms  Link                                       1 calls
       43 ms  SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables        1 calls
       46 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedCppNETCoreVersion     20 calls
       48 ms  CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo                  20 calls
       52 ms  _CheckForLanguageAndFeatureCombinationSupport  20 calls
       56 ms  GenerateSatelliteAssemblies               14 calls
       56 ms  GetAssemblyAttributes                     20 calls
       57 ms  _ComputeSkipAnalyzers                     79 calls
       60 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                23 calls
       65 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides  20 calls
       68 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs       60 calls
       70 ms  _GetProjectJsonPath                       20 calls
       73 ms  Protobuf_PrepareCompile                    4 calls
       73 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                        20 calls
       74 ms  _CopyAppConfigFile                        16 calls
      102 ms  MarkupCompilePass1                         1 calls
      104 ms  ResolveLockFileCopyLocalFiles             20 calls
      106 ms  _CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry       20 calls
      107 ms  ExpressionBuildExtension                  59 calls
      110 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                       80 calls
      111 ms  _BeforeVBCSCoreCompile                    79 calls
      113 ms  _Protobuf_GatherStaleBatched              14 calls
      117 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                      80 calls
      121 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                           59 calls
      121 ms  CreateGeneratedAssemblyInfoInputsCacheFile  20 calls
      122 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls
      122 ms  GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformForSingleTargetFramework  78 calls
      130 ms  GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker    79 calls
      135 ms  FileClassification                        59 calls
      149 ms  ValidationExtension                       59 calls
      150 ms  CopyAutoMapperAssembly                     6 calls
      155 ms  GenerateBuildDependencyFile               20 calls
      155 ms  BuildOnlySettings                         79 calls
      156 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                    20 calls
      158 ms  _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory  58 calls
      158 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                     20 calls
      158 ms  _PopulateCommonStateForGetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems  80 calls
      160 ms  _GetRestoreProjectStyle                   20 calls
      164 ms  CreateManifestResourceNames                5 calls
      183 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute   79 calls
      192 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                             59 calls
      194 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute       79 calls
      195 ms  Build                                     80 calls
      196 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                   80 calls
      196 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs          80 calls
      220 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties       79 calls
      225 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                    79 calls
      238 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                         80 calls
      254 ms  PrepareForBuild                           80 calls
      272 ms  ResolveComReferences                       1 calls
      280 ms  GenerateSerializationAssemblies            1 calls
      284 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                       78 calls
      286 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromThisProject  80 calls
      316 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                 80 calls
      345 ms  _ComputeUserRuntimeAssemblies             20 calls
      394 ms  _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways   2 calls
      402 ms  PostBuild                                  4 calls
      431 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                   80 calls
      480 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                      20 calls
      668 ms  AssignTargetPaths                         80 calls
      965 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform  80 calls
     1201 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                80 calls
     1437 ms  CoreResGen                                79 calls
     1443 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence    80 calls
     1723 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                70 calls
     1744 ms  CoreCompile                               79 calls
     3608 ms  ResolveLockFileReferences                 20 calls
     3660 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades         59 calls
     4645 ms  PostBuildEvent                             7 calls
     4820 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                 71 calls
     5002 ms  ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades        59 calls
     6157 ms  GetTargetFrameworksWithPlatformFromInnerBuilds  10 calls
     6522 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences  80 calls
     8423 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems             80 calls
    14762 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences      79 calls
    15969 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache           79 calls
    15971 ms  _ComputeReferenceAssemblies               20 calls
    16716 ms  IncrementalClean                          79 calls
    17131 ms  _HandlePackageFileConflicts               79 calls
    37032 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites        79 calls
    46860 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties  80 calls
    91992 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                 80 calls
    1123554 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                  80 calls

Task Performance Summary:
        0 ms  ProtoToolsPlatform                         4 calls
        2 ms  CreateItem                                 5 calls
        2 ms  GenerateBindingRedirects                   1 calls
        2 ms  FileClassifier                             1 calls
        3 ms  GetFrameworkPath                          79 calls
        5 ms  GetOutOfDateItems                          1 calls
        8 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides  20 calls
       10 ms  RC                                         1 calls
       25 ms  AllowEmptyTelemetry                       20 calls
       25 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                        20 calls
       28 ms  ProtoCompilerOutputs                       4 calls
       32 ms  ProtoReadDependencies                      4 calls
       42 ms  Link                                       1 calls
       43 ms  SetEnv                                     8 calls
       43 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                23 calls
       63 ms  MakeDir                                  101 calls
       84 ms  CreateCSharpManifestResourceName           7 calls
       87 ms  GetRestoreProjectStyleTask                20 calls
       99 ms  MarkupCompilePass1                         1 calls
      107 ms  AssignCulture                             81 calls
      120 ms  CL                                         2 calls
      120 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                 59 calls
      123 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                    60 calls
      128 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                     20 calls
      131 ms  Delete                                   139 calls
      169 ms  FindAppConfigFile                         79 calls
      174 ms  WriteLinesToFile                         100 calls
      182 ms  Touch                                     77 calls
      257 ms  ResolveComReference                        1 calls
      272 ms  Message                                  246 calls
      279 ms  SGen                                       1 calls
      376 ms  AddFacadesToReferences                     3 calls
      419 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                      20 calls
      826 ms  AssignTargetPath                         540 calls
      945 ms  GenerateResource                           4 calls
     1526 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                         80 calls
     1570 ms  GetDependsOnNETStandard                   57 calls
     1583 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                70 calls
     1948 ms  Hash                                      99 calls
     3071 ms  RemoveDuplicates                         158 calls
     3206 ms  GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask    70 calls
     3273 ms  JoinItems                                 20 calls
     5045 ms  Exec                                      11 calls
     5246 ms  Copy                                     234 calls
     5592 ms  FindUnderPath                            403 calls
     7557 ms  CallTarget                               219 calls
     9394 ms  ResolvePackageFileConflicts               79 calls
    13711 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                     79 calls
    91537 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                  79 calls
    1170684 ms  MSBuild                                  327 calls
```

Anyone knows if/how I can get my configuration to do the minimum required actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a nuget restore task on your project.

MSBuild command line does not execute the nuget restore task automatically but VS IDE does.

So I suggest you could add a additional target for restore.

**Note**: you should change the content target to use `Outputs="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"` to make the target find the final output file.

**Solution One**

If your projects are all net core projects, you could directly restore the missing packages like this:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:restore,build -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true
```

**Solution Two**

**Or** just integrate them into the `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="Build"
    Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' " DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" Returns="@(TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker)"
    Inputs="@(Compile);@(Content)" Outputs="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(TargetFileName)"/>
  </Target>

<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
      <Exec Command="msbuild -t:restore -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true" />
</Target>
```

**Then**, invoke the command line to build it:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build
```

**Conclusion**

I suggest you would better use **Solution One**. Once, you already restored the nuget packages, you do not have to add `-t:restore` the second time, just use `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working with dotnet framework, with pre-vs2017 csproj file format. Would your solution still work in that context?

Comment: With solution One, I'm getting `NuGet.targets(560,5): error : The path is not of a legal form.` using nuget version 5.8.1.7021

Comment: In my side, I created a net472 new sdk project on vs2017, and then add the target into my csproj file. run the command and did not face the issue.

Comment: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yucjw.png) and [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxUBG.png). Please give any detailed info to help me troubleshoot the issue or what is the version of your VS2017 and you would better update it to the latest version to ensure some new useful changes.

Comment: The errors disappear when I use `$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)`. However, building is still slow: for 120+ projects, and after building once, the subsequent builds (with no changes whatsoever) take 9+ minutes using `diagnostic` verbosity. I can see 59 instances of `Skipping target "Build" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.` I will edit my post the performances summary.

Comment: That is the best solution we tried on it so far. MSBuild command line is not the VS IDE build and it is a lightweight build tool for build. However, the `up-to-date` of VS IDE build will monitor the whole build process and will skip the whole build process due to the unchanged info. But MSBuild Command line will not and if you get the same hehavior, you have to write every `input,output` for each custom target(not only build target). But that goes against the lightweight design.

Comment: And I cannot find any related write function of vs ide build. If it has, it is too large. So if you make msbuild command line behaves the same as VS IDE build. That is almost impossible and hard work.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there would be a kind of "parent" target that would be able to declare whether or not to run the whole build process. I will then try to see what I can achieve through adding `input,output` to some or all targets. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Do you think the `-graphBuild` may help me?